# Multiple og meta tags on single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, share-open-graph

I have a single page on my site suppose example.com/content . That page have a tab contents like tab1 and tab2. When user visit  example.com/content#tab1 the tab1 will be active and the tab2 content will be hidden. Now I want to set differnt og:description for example.com/content, example.com/content#tab1 and example.com/content#tab2. The active tab content will be the og:description.

I try to handle this using javascript but can not change the og:description.  is it possible to implement a script for crawling specific metadata for each `#tab` URL?  The sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Your Website Title">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg">
    <meta name="og:description" content="Default description for your website">
    <title>Your Website</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            updateOGDescription(); 
            $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
                updateOGDescription(); 
            });
        });

        function updateOGDescription() {
            var hash = window.location.hash;
            var description = "Default description for your website";
            
            if (hash === '#slot1') {
                description = $("#slot1-content").text().trim(); 
            } else if (hash === '#slot2') {
                description = $("#slot2-content").text().trim(); 
            }

            $('meta[property="og:description"]').attr('content', description);
        }

        function openTab(tabId) {
            $('.tab').removeClass('active');
            $('#' + tabId).addClass('active');
            $('.tab-content').hide();
            $('#' + tabId + '-content').show();
            updateOGDescription(); 
            window.location.hash = tabId;
        }

        $(window).on('load', function() {
            var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
            if (hash) {
                openTab(hash);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tabbed Content Example</h1>
    <div>
        <!-- Tab navigation -->
        <button onclick="openTab('slot1')">Tab 1</button>
        <button onclick="openTab('slot2')">Tab 2</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- Tab content -->
        <div id="slot1" class="tab active">
            <h2>Tab 1 Content</h2>
            <div id="slot1-content" class="tab-content">
                <p>This is the content of Tab 1.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="slot2" class="tab">
            <h2>Tab 2 Content</h2>
            <div id="slot2-content" class="tab-content">
                <p>This is the content of Tab 2.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That kind of metadata has to be set on the server side. When you share a link on social media, they will fetch the HTML from your page and parse it to find the metadata. They will not run javascript on it. Furthermore, anything after '#' will not be sent to your server, so you cannot use _hash URLs_, you need to use a path or query param to get a distinct og:description